# Tax calculation using javascript

Tags: javascript

I develop E-commerce app.

I display the List of product using this array.

Here is my cartProduct array.

```
      Cartproduct=[
  {
    "P_ID": 1,
    "P_TITLE": "Martina",
    "PRICE_REGULAR": 194,
    "PRICE_SALE": 161,
    "P_TAX": [
      {
        "NAME": "CGST",
        "PERCENTAGE": 9
      },
      {
        "NAME": "SGST",
        "PERCENTAGE": 9
      },
      {
        "NAME": "IGST",
        "PERCENTAGE": 18
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "P_ID": 2,
    "P_TITLE": "Kristen",
    "P_TYPE": "simple",
    "PRICE_REGULAR": 130,
    "PRICE_SALE": 174,
     "P_TAX": [
      {
        "NAME": "CGST",
        "PERCENTAGE": 5
      },
      {
        "NAME": "SGST",
        "PERCENTAGE": 5
      },
      {
        "NAME": "IGST",
        "PERCENTAGE": 10
      }
    ],
  }]
```

I need to calculate Tax amount in this cartProduct array.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: The question is unclear, please provide more details.

Comment: What are the different entries of `"P_TAX"` representing? Are they all to be included in the calculation? --- What are you actually having issue with?

Comment: `(NET/100)*TAX` should give you the amount of tax based on the percentage, as for doing it with what you've provided, no. StackOverflow is not a coding service, also I wouldn't recommend doing these calculations in JavaScript as it's not the best at handling floating point numbers.

Comment: @ANISUNDAR Maybe this will be helpful: http://jsbin.com/hetusiciji/edit?js,console

Comment: @abhishekkannojia.I tried to this But i am getting this err Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

Comment: That means your array `Cartproduct` is not defined in that scope. How are you getting the array. Also check for typos.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia.It's work.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tax=Cartproduct.reduce(function(tax,product){
  product["P_TAX"].forEach(function(t){
    tax+=product["PRICE_SALE"]*t.PERCENTAGE/100;
  });
  return tax;
},0);
```

Simply reduce it.